# Optimal way to use tkinter and openpyxl to iterate through a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, tkinter, openpyxl

I'm a complete Python beginner, trying to make a GUI which allows the user to select an Excel file, from which some data will be extracted and analyzed. For the GUI I am using tkinter, and for the Excel operations I am using openpyxl. **The code that I currently have works, but when the Excel file selected is large, the runtime is stupidly long (a 10,000 row x 20 column spreadsheet took about an hour to iterate through, and just got slower as time went by). Also, the GUI stops responding for the duration of the iteration.** I had previously made the program practically identically using MATLAB, and it worked beautifully, with the whole iteration process taking only one or two seconds, so something is definitely funky here. Now I know this is a problem with me and not Python, so I was hoping you guys could help point me in the right direction of how to fix it.

Here are some simplified examples of what I'm working with to help illustrate my situation. I need to go through each row of the spreadsheet, check a certain value in that row to see if it matches what I want, and if it does, I store some data from that row.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'some_garbage.xlsx', read_only=True).worksheets[0]
all_data = wb.cell
desiredColor = 'Purple'
foodStorage = []

for row in range(2, wb.max_row + 1):
    print(row)
    if(all_data(row, 1).value == desiredColor):
        foodStorage.append(all_data(row,2))
        print('I found purple! Yee')
```

[image: Example spreadsheet. Unfortunately my real data isn't about colors and foods]

**Should I be using a module other than openpyxl for this task, or am I just making some mistake that keeps openpyxl from performing at its full potential? 
Should I be using threading, either to speed up the iteration process, or to ensure that my GUI window doesn't go all "Not Responding" on me while the iteration is doing its thing?**

I tried to search for questions regarding similar issues, but I wasn't really able to find quite what I was looking for, most likely due to my lack of ability to put my problem into the proper words. So, I apologize profusely in advance for asking something which has probably been answered a million times before. I'd appreciate any help you could give, and thanks for your time.

Comment: You should double check the value of `max_row`. When I use this on my end it returns the max possible row for the spreadsheet instead of the last row. For example I have a spreadsheet with 4777 lines however `max_row` returned `65536` lines.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, mine doesn't do that. It returns the last row just as I would expect. Perhaps it's merely a discrepancy between our spreadsheets?

Comment: Its a common problem. Several bug reports exist. That said if its not affecting you then that is good. Just need to figure out what the problem is. I think it is the large number of columns. When I use openpyxl I normally reduce my spreadsheets down to only the columns I need to compare and then from that create another spreadsheet with all the data. Otherwise loading the file just to be read takes forever and then running the code can take a long time as well.

Comment: When you say reduce the spreadsheets, do you mean that you simply go into Excel and delete the columns that you don't want? Or is there a way to specify to openpyxl to only care about certain columns?

Comment: I manually delete the columns I don't want. This has helped me improve speed from anywhere between 20% to 90% faster. It is not a problem form me to do that but i am sure it would be preferable if you didn't need to do something like that.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to not have to go through that extra step. And while reducing the number of columns certainly increases speed, it still runs quite slowly. For the very simple example I posted, which has only two columns, the loop still takes over 10 minutes for 10,000 rows. There must be some major inefficiency with my process but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Ya it should not take 10 min. I have a spreadsheet with 350k lines and it take about 10 min to compare data. What I am doing is comparing 2000 lines to the 350k line to find matching info from 2 different columns. This only take about 10 min.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on something similar but with larger data.

I had a similar problem and I assume it occurs because of the processor trying to run both the excel iteration as well as the root.mainloop() on the same thread, which not only slows the process but also hangs your application making the GUI non-responsive. For this to work correctly, you will have to call your worker(Iteration) function in a different thread than your root.mainloop(). The best way to do this would be to define multiple classes for GUI, Worker and the App and call the Worker function threads from your App class while your GUI runs in a different loop.

A simple sample for the same-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox
import threading
import time

#base GUI Class
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root, runCommand):
        mf = ttk.Frame(root, padding="5 5 5 5")
        mf.grid(column=0, row=0)
        mf.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        mf.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Global Values
        self.Fnm = tk.StringVar(root, "SearchFile.xlsx")
        self.Ncol = tk.StringVar(root, "D")
        self.Vcol = tk.StringVar(root, "C")
        # Label
        tk.Label(mf, text="File Name").grid(column=1, row=1, pady=6)
        tk.Label(mf, text="Name Col").grid(column=1, row=3, pady=6)
        tk.Label(mf, text="Value Col").grid(column=3, row=3, pady=6)

        # components
        self.fname = ttk.Entry(mf, width=18, textvariable=self.Fnm)
        self.nmCol = ttk.Entry(mf, width=6, textvariable=self.Ncol)
        self.valCol = ttk.Entry(mf, width=6, textvariable=self.Vcol)
        self.but = ttk.Button(mf, text="Refresh", command=runCommand)
        self.pgbar = ttk.Progressbar(mf, orient="horizontal", mode="determinate")

        # Design
        self.fname.grid(column=2, row=1, pady=3, columnspan=3)
        self.nmCol.grid(column=2, row=3, pady=3)
        self.valCol.grid(column=4, row=3, pady=3)
        self.but.grid(column=2, row=2, columnspan=2)
        self.pgbar.grid(column=1,row=4,columnspan=4)

    def refresh(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        return [self.Fnm.get(), self.Ncol.get(), self.Vcol.get()]

#Base process Class
class Proc:
    def __init__(self, dets,pgbar,but):
        self.Fnm = dets[0]
        self.Ncol = dets[1]
        self.Vcol = dets[2]
        self.pg=pgbar
        self.butt=but

    def refresh(self):
        self.butt['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.pg.start()
        #ATTENTION:Enter Your process Code HERE
        for _ in range(5):
            time.sleep(2)#Longggg work
        self.pg.stop()
        #Any search/sort algorithm to be used
        #You can use self.pg.step() to be more specific for how the progress bar proceeds
        messagebox.showinfo("Process Done","Success")
        self.butt['state'] = 'enabled'

#Base Application Class
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.gui = GUI(self.master, self.runit)

    def runit(self):
        self.search = Proc(self.gui.get(),self.gui.pgbar,self.gui.but)
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.search.refresh)
        self.thread1.start()

def main():
    app = tk.Tk()
    gui = App(app)
    app.title("Refresh Search File")
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As for the iteration through the data, you can checkout [this](https://github.com/bhaskar-nair2/MedSort/blob/master/searchSetup.py) for a more efficient code.

I can't write all the code here as it is too long, so please refer the links

Comment: Please refrain from linking to external sources without provide the basic concept within the answer. If for any reason your links were to break this answer would no longer be of any use to anyone.

Comment: Alright @Mike-SMT , I'll put some more logic here, but I would really avoid putting the code, it's very very long but if you say that it might be better, I won't mind.